# Find all the self-conjugate partitions

Tags: integer-partitions

Find all the self-conjugate partitions of 2018, whose second part is 3. Find all
the self-conjugate partitions of 2019, whose second part is 3.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Do you know the correspondence between self-conjugate partitions and partitions into distinct odd parts?

Comment: What do you mean by "are made up of distinct odd parts"? Do you mean [this bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Conjugate_and_self-conjugate_partitions)?

Comment: Yea, or " n is equal to the number of partitions of n into distinct odd parts"

Comment: That's not true. For instance, for $n=4$, the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct odd parts is $1$, not $4$.

Comment: Okay, I have no idea on how to approach this.